# Function with custom data array

Tags: arrays, json, swift, class

I have following function call:

```
@IBAction func submitCourse(sender: AnyObject) {
    // print("Enter")
        getTime( (courseName.text!), courseCode: (codeName.text!))
        print(classes[0].end);
        //print("ASODASODJASDJASASDASDD \(string1)")
}
```

And custom class of datas:

```
class ClassSchedule {
var course: String?
var code: String?
var section: String?
var start: String?
var end: String?

init(course: String, code: String, section: String, start: String, end: String)
{
    self.course = course
    self.code = code
    self.section = section
    self.start = start
    self.end = end

}

}
```

And requesting of JSON object, parsing it into arrays of `classSchedule`:

```
 // Read the JSON
    do {
        let data: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: url)
        if let jsonResult: NSDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
        {
            //////ARRAY///////
            let dataArray = jsonResult["data"] as! NSArray
            //////
            let arrayLength = dataArray.count
            var count = 0


            print("TOTAL OF CLASSES: \(arrayLength)");

            for item in dataArray
            {              
                 classes.append(ClassSchedule(course: "TEMP", code: "TEMP", section: "TEMP", start:"TEMP", end:"TEMP") )

                classes[count].course = item["subject"] as! String
                classes[count].code = item["catalog_number"] as! String
                classes[count].section = item["section"] as! String
                print("Subject: \(classes[count].course!) \(classes[count].code!)");
                print("Section: \(classes[count].section!)");
              // print("Section: \(section_numb)");

                let subjectArray = item["classes"] as! NSArray
                for item2 in subjectArray{

                    let dateDictionary = item2["date"] as! NSDictionary
                    //let startTime = dateDictionary["start_time"]!
                    //self.performSelectorOnMainThread("updateIPLabel:", withObject: startTime, waitUntilDone: false)
                    //let endTime = dateDictionary["end_time"]!
                    classes[count].start = dateDictionary["start_time"] as! String
                    classes[count].end = dateDictionary["end_time"] as! String
                    string1 = classes[count].start!
                    print("START TIME: \(classes[count].start!)");
                    print("End Time: \( classes[count].end!)");
                    print("")
                   count += 1
                    print(count)

                }

            }
            //let subject = dataArray["subject"]
        }

    } catch {
        print("bad things happened")
    }

    print("ASDIAWDWD: \(classes[0].section)")
   // print("ASDIAWDWASDASDD: \(classes[1].section)")
    }).resume()
```

Those print statements in the function works fine and prints wanted datas.
I'm having trouble returning the filled array of `ClassSchedule` to `ViewController.swift`.

I tried declaring the array as global variable but it still gives me error at `print(classes[0].end);` saying Array index out of range.

I have a feeling that it's due to the asynchronous requests of JSON but don't know how to fix it.

Comment: just to make sure. you use the `dataTaskWithRequest` function to process the data right?

Comment: no i'm using dataTaskwithURL. Does it make difference if i use dataTaskWithRequest?

Comment: oo, actually no :D. well, how about if you check the `state` of the task before print out the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is because it's an Asynchronous call. You have to keep a local array within API call success and after all processing, you have to have a callback to send the data back to the caller. i.e., you have to have a block as a parameter while making an API call.

**Update**

```
func yourAPICall(addNecessaryParameters, failure: NSError -> (), completion: NSArray -> ()) {
    // API call and parsing goes here

    var returnArray = [AnyObject]()
    if let _ = error {
        failure(error!)
    }
    else {
        completion(returnArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: could you elaborate on 'you have to have a block as a parameter while making an API call.' Are you saying I should pass in the object array as a parameter into the function of json calls?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can now get the array on the viewController.swift, but new problem came up. I only can access it INSIDE the getTime() function call. I've updated question with working code so far. Please take a look.

Comment: The fetched data from API call will be returned in the success block. You have to assign that data to the actual array of the viewController inside the block. If not the array won't be initialised at all.

Comment: I've updated getTime function to have success block. I've defined both 'classes' and 'classesTemp' as a global variable in the app. Updated code in the question and it's still not working. Would you please take a look?

Comment: This print statement is called asynchronously - print("Pass it to tableview \(classesTemp[0].end) ") whereas, this print statement print("IN VIEASDASDW CONTROLLER \(classesTemp[0].end) "); is called way too early. This is due to asynchronous api call. API call will be executing in background and the second print statement gets called immediately due to synchronous execution. The first print statement will be called asynchronously after API success. You can do a reload data for tableView when the api succeeds.

Comment: I don't have tableView class defined in the viewController. I have separate file for managing tableView From what you have mentioned, there's no way to have that array of objects outside of the getTime function call?? My original intention is to get the array of objects, when 'submit' button is pressed, call prepareForSegue function to pass array to tableview

Comment: I tried moving the function call inside the tableView: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446396/swift-tableview

Comment: You can't access the array outside of block. You can assign the array from block to view controller property and then push/present the view controllers. Never do any api call inside tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.